# How to determine data used for plotting polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I have this shapefile of soil characteristics in Massachusetts, but when looking at its attribute table, I can't determine what values are being used to plot each polygon. This becomes an issue when I export the shapefile as a CSV to make calculations on (due to its size), as I can't figure out how to import the CSV and plot these polygons again from it.

As far as I can tell, the only columns that may indicate unique values for each of the polygons are the SHAPE_Leng and SHAPE_Area columns, but I am not sure if these can be utilized in a similar way to plot these polygons as Lat/Long columns. A few other columns seem to be somewhat unique but end of repeating themselves over many rows.

I've included a picture as well to further explain the situation.

[image: Here's just a snippet of the data I am looking at]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shapefiles geometries doesnt exist in the attribute table.

You can:

1. Save Vector Layer as csv, with GEOMETRY: AS_WKT . This will create a text representation of the geometries
   [image]
   [image]
2. Process the csv
3. Import it back to QGIS using "Add delimited text layer" (Ctrl+Shift+T), set Geometry definition = WKT
   [image]